# mongodb creating unique index: significance of ": 1"

Tags: mongodb

Following is how unique constraint is created in mongodb:

```
db.members.createIndex( { "user_id": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

What is the significance of "1" in above command. Above command seems a bit counter-intuitive to me because of that "1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly from the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-index/#create-an-index-on-a-single-field):

> a value of 1 specifies an index that orders items in ascending order.
>   A value of -1 specifies an index that orders items in descending
>   order.

So it creates an index on your user_id field in ascending order and the values can only be unique.